# No click method defined on element when created via web_sys

Tags: rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen, web-sys

In the JavaScript console, I can execute the following to create an `<input>` element and demonstrate that it has a `click` method.

```
let input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "file";
console.log(input.click);
// ƒ click() { [native code] }
```

If I attempted to do the following in Rust compiled to `wasm`, I get an error:

```
let document: Document = Document::new().unwrap();
let input: Element = document.create_element("input").unwrap();
input.set_attribute("type", "file").unwrap();

# For debugging purposes, save a reference to a global variable so I can inspect it from the JavaScript console
let input_jsval : JsValue = input.clone().into();
js_sys::Reflect::set(&js_sys::global(), &JsValue::from_str("debug_input"), &input_jsval).unwrap();

# Attempt to click it
let input_html_element: HtmlElement = input_jsval.clone().into();
input_html_element.click();
```

When I run the `wasm` tests it produces:

```
failures:

---- wasm_tests::tests::input_test output ----
    log output:
    
    error output:
        wasm-bindgen: imported JS function that was not marked as `catch` threw an error: getObject(...).click is not a function
        
        Stack:
        TypeError: getObject(...).click is not a function
            at http://127.0.0.1:8000/wasm-bindgen-test:589:25
```

If I check the JavaScript console, I can see that there is no `click` method on the reference that I saved.

```
debug_input.click
// undefined
```

So why is it that when I create an `<input>` via JavaScript it gets a `click` method but if I do essentially the same thing via `wasm` it does not? I suspect the conversion from `Element` to `HtmlElement` via `JsValue` is lossy? Is there a more direct conversion?

Answer (score 1):

Q1: Is there a more direct conversion for `Element` into `HtmlElement`?

A1: Yes, if you know it really is an `HtmlElement` then you can `let input_html_element: HtmlElement = input.dyn_into().unwrap();` . However, this will fail if the input isn't really an `HtmlElement` and this case, it's not.

Q2: Why wouldn't it be an `HtmlElement`?

A2: [The MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) that `Document::createElement` will return "[a] new `HTMLElement` ... if the document is an `HTMLDocument`, which is the most common case. Otherwise a new `Element` is returned. The `Document::new()` API doesn't get a reference to the current window's `document`, rather it creates a new (non-HTML) document. Instead, use:

```
let document: Document = web_sys::window().unwrap().document().unwrap();
```

Comment: Nit: Use `.unwrap_throw()`.

Comment: It's demonstration code. I wouldn't suggest using `unwrap` (and friends) in real usage.